# How does Australian Aboriginal totemism compare to its Native American parallels?

Tags: comparative, indigenous-australian

I was surprised to find out that the concept of [totemism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totem) is present in Australian Aboriginal tales. Up until today, I was under the - obviously mistaken - impression that it was a concept unique to the indigenous cultures of the Americas. I find the fact that the same concept evolved in cultures so far apart absolutely fascinating, but I can't help but wonder how similar Australian Aboriginal totemism actually is to its more well known of Native American counterparts. The one interesting difference I found out about is that indigenous Australians didn't build totem poles. This makes sense, indigenous Australians are nomadic and monumental sculptures aren't very practical when you move around all the time.

What other differences are there? How does Australian Aboriginal totemism compare to its Native American parallels?